# Automatic/scheduled check for open ports on list of servers

Tags: nagios, port, nmap

I need a way to configure a scheduled check for open ports on a list of servers and to get notified if something has changed from last check.

what's the best way to do it? If there is some solution which talk with Nagios it would be even better.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use [check_udp](http://nagiosplugins.org/man/check_udp) and [check_tcp](http://nagiosplugins.org/man/check_tcp) if you know which ports should be open. This will check if a certain port is available for nagios on a remote server. You can add a service (check_udp/tcp) for each port you want to check on each server.

If you want to look for 'new/unidentified' open ports on a remote server, you could use [check_scan](http://www.altsec.info/check_scan.html). This will check for changes in the open ports. The first time it runs, it will create a baseline, the following checks will be checked against this baseline.

Comment: I want to check all ports (like using nmap) and on a bunch of servers :) In the simplest way to describe it, it's like to run nmap (on each of the servers) every 5 hours and to be notified if something has changed.

Comment: Ah sorry, got it the other way around, I'll update my answer :)

Comment: Notify your hosting company and/or network and security administrators before running port scans or you may be blacklisted.

Comment: @ramruma: Around here, we assume that the people asking are the people that should be notified.

Comment: @BartDeVos Thank you! I've run through some options (like PBNJ, nmap-diff etc) and finally settled down with this [check_scan](http://www.altsec.info/check_scan.html).